# Strange caching behaviour on cloned PHP / Apache based website

Tags: php, apache, caching, browser-cache

I have just created a clone of a web system in order make a development version.
The clone is on the same server, I have copied all files, database structure etc. The vhost.conf and httpd.include are identical (bar the domain name obviously).

The server is running CentOS linux with Apache.

Everything is working except for a bizarre behaviour that only happens on the new clone.

I have a page (let's call it page1) which runs server side PHP functions and unsets a session variable when it is loaded. From this page is a link to the page that sets that session variable (page2).

If I click back to page1 from page2 using the browser's back button the page is (apparently) being loaded from cache and therefore not running any of the server side functions including the one to unset the session variable. If I click refresh/reload then the page acts as expected and the server side functions run and the session variable is unset.

This behaviour does not occur on the original despite it being identical.

Of course there must be *something* different but I can't think of anything. It must be something server side as all files are identical.

Can anyone suggest something I haven't tried yet?

**EDIT:**
Now, even more bizarrely, it seems to be working fine.
Perhaps it was a Firefox blip. Seems rather odd though and worrying that something like that could happen.
I think I need some more fail-safes.

Comment: When destroying or unsetting a session variable you should use a header to redirect or refresh the page, else you will see this behavior because a session is still a cookie.

Comment: @Lawrence That's all well and good, but it neither explains nor solves my problem.